# In Haskell how can I override the (==) and (/=) operators for a type class?

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading

Say I have something like this

```
class Circle c where
    x :: c -> Float
    y :: c -> Float
    radius :: c -> Float

data Location = Location { locationX :: Float
                         , locationY :: Float
                         } deriving (Show, Eq)

data Blob = Location { blobX :: Float
                     , blobY :: Float
                     , blobRadius :: Float,
                     , blobRating :: Int
                     } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Circle Location where
    x = locationX
    y = locationY
    radius = pure 0

instance Circle Blob where
    x = blobX
    y = blobY
    radius = blobRadius
```

Say for example I want Circle types to be equal if their x and y points are equal. How can I compare instances of the type class with the (==) and (/=) operators. I know I can do something like this, but is it possible to overload the operators?

```
equal :: Circle a => Circle b => a -> b -> Bool
equal a b = (x a == x b && y a == y b)
```

I want to be able to compare with

`(Location 5.0 5.0) == (Blob 5.0 5.0 ... )` should give me True

Comment: What do you mean by overload exactly? How does `(==)` should work for other stuff?

Comment: `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`; you cannot compare values of two different types, even if both types implement the same type class.

Comment: Being explicit and defining `radius = const 0` would probably be a good idea. `radius` is not an arbitrary `Applicative`; it's a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Zeroth**, some standard imports:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
```

---

**First**, this is not a good idea. `a==b` should only be true if `a` and `b` are (for all purposes relevant to the user) interchangeable – that's clearly not the case for two circles which merely happen to share the same center point!

**Second**, it's probably not a good idea to make `Circle` a typeclass in the first place. A typeclass only makes sense when you want to abstract over something that can't directly be expressed with just a parameter. But if you just want to attach different “payloads” to points in space, a more sensible approach might be to define something like

```
data Located a = Located {x,y :: ℝ, payload :: a}
```

If, as seems to be the case, you actually want to allow *different instances of `Circle`* to coexist and be comparable at runtime, then a typeclass is entirely the wrong choice. That would be an OO class. Haskell doesn't have any built-in notion of those, but you could just use

```
data Blob = Blob
   { x,y :: ℝ
   , radius :: ℝ
   , rating :: Maybe Int }
```

and no other types.

https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/

**Third**, the instance that you asked for can, **theoretically speaking**, be defined as

```
instance (Circle a) => Eq a where
  (==) = (==)`on`(x &&& y)
```

But this would be a truely horrible idea. It would be a catch-all instance: whenever you compare *anything*, the compiler would check “is it of the form `a`?” (literally *anything* is of that form) “oh great, then said instance tells me how to compare this.” Only later would it look at the `Circle` requirement.

The **correct** solution is to not define any such `Eq` instance at all. Your types already have `Eq` instances individually, that should generally be the right thing to use – no need to express it through the `Circle` class at all, just give any function which needs to do such comparisons the constraint `(Circle a, Eq a) => ...`.

Of course, these instances would then *not* just compare the location but the entire data, which, as I said, is a good thing. If you actually want to compare only part of the structure, well, make that explicit! Use not `==` itself, but extract the relevant parts and compare those. A useful helper for this could be

```
location :: Circle a => a -> Location
location c = Location (x c) (y c)
```

...then you can, for any `Circle` type, simply write `` (==)`on`location `` instead of `(==)`, to disregard any other information except the location. Or write out `` (==)`on`(x &&& y) `` directly, which can easily be tweaked to other situations.

Answer (score 2):

Two circles that share a common center aren't necessarily equal, but they are *concentric*; that's what you should write a function to check.

```
concentric :: (Circle a, Circle b) => a -> b -> Bool
concentric c1 c2 = x c1 == x c2 && y c1 == y c2
```